# How can I relocate the Transform tool in Sculpt mode (Blender2.81)?

Tags: sculpting

I tried to relocate the position of this tool but the same time my mesh (its unmasked part exactly) was also transformed. 
[image]

Well If i mask out the whole object I can manipulate the tool's position, but I think it is an uneffective workflow to mask out the whole mesh everytime I would try to relocate the tool.

[image]

Is there any way to relocate the Tranform tool in Sculpt mode without affecting the unmasked part of the mesh?

Comment: @RobertGützkow see my answer about using the 3D cursor with Transform Pivot Point

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers!

I guess i wasn't clear enough but my problem only concerned with Sculpt mode.

However i've found a solution: Expand Mask by Topology (shift+a) and transform gizmo automatically jumps to middle of the unmasked are. IMO still an unintuitive and cumbersome method, but better than nothing. It'd be great If we can manipulate the tranform gizmo in sculpt mode independently.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a somewhat better alternative than Bön suggests.

If you switch to the layout mode and set your pivot point to be "3D Cursor" then you can `shift-rmb` move it around while you're in the sculpt mode:

[image]

An obvious benefit is that it preserves the mask, as opposed to the `shift-a` selection.

Unfortunately, it's not as precise and you can only place the pivot on the surface (which might be enough for the simple moves/rotations). I looked around blender market and experimented with "Pivot Transform", which kinda works – you can get the pivot gizmo on screen via a hotkey, but it won't preserve the sculpt mode and will kick you out into the object mode after you're done (you can get back with `ctrl-tab`, though). The combination of the two gets you really close to that popular sculpting software and its gizmo.

Comment: thank you! exactly what i was looking for

Comment: one annoying thing w/ the 3d cursor method is if you want to rotate from the center of a limb. you have go into edit mode > select edge loop > move cursor to selected... A little more cumbersom than shift+right clicking.

Comment: I love you Farcaller, saved me a million headaches!

Answer (score 0):

*Sculpt > Set Pivot > Pivot to Surface Under Cursor*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.